# Porting an existing site to a static site generator

Tags: php, content-management-system, static-site, sculpin

I have an existing site that I need to port over to a Static Site Generator. I'm planning on using Sculpin.

I already have other Composer dependencies in the directory. I'd like to use Composer to install Sculpin in the existing site directory, generate the site, seamlessly add existing pages, and then sync with the existing GitHub repository.

I'm not currently interested in writing in Markdown. I'd like to keep most of the site as-is. The first step after getting the page running again is to replace site-wide headers and footers with generated content.

The question - could the port really be this simple? When I initialize Sculpin, is it going to wipe out anything I have already built? I'd rather not start over in an entirely new directory and rebuild the entire LESS/PHP/JS/Git infrastructure.

Thanks!

Comment: If it seems simple, why not just make a copy of the site and just try it?

Comment: could you clarify what are you trying to achieve? Sculpin generates files into output_dev and won't wipe out anything.

Comment: @ŁukaszRysiak - I have an existing HTML/CSS/JS site. I want to use a SSG to remove static footers and headers on every page and replace them with with generated footers and headers as a first step. I want to initialize Sculpin in the current working directory and have pages to work as they currently do. I was primarily concerned I cannot initialize in the current working directory before I begin to use Sculpin features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your clarification in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844922/porting-an-existing-site-to-a-static-site-generator?noredirect=1#comment52271566_31844922) the answer is: yes, you can initialize Sculpin in your site directory - it shouldn't delete anything.

I'd do it this way:

```
 2. create a copy of your current page
 2. initialize sculpin in the copied directory
 3. extract pages content into markdown files and put them in ./source/_posts/
 4. prepare layout with new headers and footers
 5. run sculpin generate
 6. check result in output_dev
 7. fix errors and regenerate
```

Sculpin is nice because it copies all the files that are in your sculpin directory to generated page - if you put some .html files there, they'll end up in generated folder.

Only problem could be that if you have pages (html files), that have the same filename as the result of the process of generating content from markdown they'd probably be overwritten in output directory.

Oww, you also mentioned composer and getting sculpin from github - yes, this could go wrong - why do you want to have local sculpin copy instead of global install - it's not needed in page source - you only need layout and config there.